# Confidence Interval Calculation

Tags: matlab, distributions, probability

I have temperature data of July 1991 to 2007, and wants to find the Confidence Interval at 95%, which distribution is best fit the data, Z or T. Please give me reason also.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for Cross Validated i don't know that. Actually i want to calculate the Confidence interval using 17 years July Temperature data, i don't know which distribution to use...

Comment: Ahsan, please do not re-post questions. If you want to add more information, use the "edit" link right below the question.

Comment: okay, actually this was my first post, it won't happen again.